# Hide Payment Method for Grand Total 0 in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, ccavenue, payment-method

Please someone share the code to avoid payment method for grand total 0. We are using CCavenue and COD for payments.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has the option for this in admin

> System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Zero Subtotal Checkout

Here is the Magento official documentation

Ref link: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/zero-subtotal-checkout.html